# What type for an integer of more than 4 bytes?

Tags: c++, integer

I have to use unsigned integers that could span to more than 4 bytes, what type should I use?

PS Sorry for the "noobism" but that's it :D

NB: I need integers because i have to do divisions and care only for the integer parts and this way int are useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*long long*, 64 bit integer... [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz(VS.80).aspx) you can find some reference about the data types and ranges...

Comment: Use <stdint> as described in CesarB's answer for a *portable* solution.  GCC doesn't understand __int64, MSVC6 (and possibly 2003) don't understand "long long", and neither is a standard.

Comment: if you require more than 4 bytes, this is not the cleanest way.

Comment: Actually, "long long" *is* in a standard, C99, and will be in C++0x according to Wikipedia.

Answer (score 12):

Simply include <stdint.h> and use int64_t and uint64_t (since you want unsigned, you want uint64_t).

There are several other useful variants on that header, like the least variants (uint_least64_t is a type with at least 64 bits) and the fast variants (uint_fast64_t is the fastest integer type with at least 64 bits). Also very useful are intptr_t/uintptr_t (large enough for a void * pointer) and intmax_t/uintmax_t (largest type).

And if for some reason your compiler doesn't have a <stdint.h> (since IIRC it's a C standard, not a C++ one), you can use Boost's [boost/cstdint.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/integer/cstdint.htm) (which you can use even if you do have a <stdint.h>, since in that case it should simply forward to the compiler's header).

Comment: <stdint.h> is in C99, not older C standards, for what it's worth. Furthermore, an implementation must provides uint64_t and int64_t if and only if it provides the corresponding 64 bit integer type. A C99 implementation is not required to provide one, but it is extremely likely to.

Answer (score 5):

Take your pick:

`long long` (–9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807)

`unsigned long long`:  (0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615)

Answer (score 2):

If you need really long integers (arbitrary precision), you could also try the [gmp](http://gmplib.org/) library, which also provides a C++ class based interface.

Answer (score 1):

unsigned long long - it is at least 64 bits long